# Send email using GMail API in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, gmail, sendmail, urlfetch

I have a raw email (tested on playground and working) and I want to send it with Google's [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) from Google Apps Script.

I can't find the right syntax for the request:

```
var RequestUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/emailAccount/messages/send";

var RequestArguments = {
    muteHttpExceptions:true,
    headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
             'GData-Version': '3.0',
             'Content-Type': "message/rfc822",
             },
    payload: {"raw":raw},
    method:"post"
  };    

var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(RequestUrl,RequestArguments);
```

What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: What error(s) do you experience?

Comment: You should start by reading over my [Debugging External Host Communication blog post](https://mogsdad.wordpress.com/2015/09/09/debugging-external-host-communication-with-urlfetchapp/), and using some of those techniques to examine any info coming back from the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my question:

```
var RequestArguments = {
  headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token},
  method: "post",
  contentType: "application/json",
  payload: JSON.stringify(jsonMessage)
};
```

jsonMessage is the whole message, not only the raw part!

Answer (score 3):

In Google Apps Script, you can use the [Advanced Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail) without needing to fuss with the Web API directly. Remember, the service must be [enabled before use](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced).

```js
/**
 * Send a raw RFC 2822 formatted and base64url encoded email
 * using the Advanced Gmail service.
 *
 * From http://stackoverflow.com/a/35073785/1677912
 *
 * @param {String}  raw  RFC 2822 formatted and base64url encoded message
 *
 * @returns {String}     Message ID of the message (now in Sent Messages).
 */
function sendRawMessage( raw ) {
  var message = Gmail.newMessage();
  message.raw = raw;
  var sentMsg = Gmail.Users.Messages.send(message, 'me');
  return sentMsg.id;
}
```

Comment: That is true, but I want to send a email from an account which is not the effective User.

Comment: That's a big detail to leave out, don't you think?

Comment: @Mogsdad is there a way to do this with the advanced API on behalf of another user? i.e. they've already authorised my app, how do I pass the oauth token with the advanced service?