# Send email with Google Apps Script - Gmail API

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I am trying to create the "raw" parameter from the solution that Mogsdad provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35073785/4743375).

I have come to the below solution

```
/**
 * Send a raw RFC 2822 formatted and base64url encoded email
 * using the Advanced Gmail service.
 *
 * From http://stackoverflow.com/a/35073785/1677912
 *
 * @param {String}  raw  RFC 2822 formatted and base64url encoded message
 *
 * @returns {String}     Message ID of the message (now in Sent Messages).
 */
function sendRawMessage( raw ) {
  var message = Gmail.newMessage();
  message.raw = raw;
  var sentMsg = Gmail.Users.Messages.send(message, 'me');
  return sentMsg.id;
}

function rawMessage(){

  const messageBody = `
  this is a test message
  `;

  var raw = (
  "From: foo@gmail.com\r\n" +
  "To: foo@gmail.com\r\n" +
  "Subject: Subject Text\r\n\r\n" +

  messageBody
);

var encodedMsg = Utilities.base64Encode(raw).replace(/=+$/, ''); //the replace removes the equals after
var myId = sendRawMessage( encodedMsg );
  Logger.log(myId);
}
```

But when I run the function I get the below error and I can't seem to figure out what the unexpected token is.

```
API call to gmail.users.messages.send failed with error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.
```

My end goal is to be able to send an email through the Gmail API but not have to "...fuss with the Web API directly."

Comment: `sendRawMessage()` is undefined

Comment: @Cooper I am using the function that Mogsdad provided in the linked post. I will update my post to include that function so there is no confusion.

Comment: It looks that you haven't enabled the Gmail Advanced Service as was instructed in the referred Mogdad's answer.